# One CSS style broke menu

Tags: php, html, css

I am creating a simple website. I have three files `menu.php` and `login.php` and `style.css`. When I include the menu (it has the style for menu divs inside `menu.php`) and uses `style.css`. It will break the layout of my menu. I tried to use `<style scoped>` and `#mydiv{ @import "style.css"}` but the results are the same.

Example code can be find [here](https://github.com/M4fin/Blog/tree/MHJ).

Normal menu:

[image]

Menu if I use style for registration form:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your style tag should be above the menu-div

move your styles to the above menu-div

try it!

Comment: I tried style above `menu-div` and in `menu-div` by `<style scoped>` and i tried style in `<head>` in `<!DOCTYPE html>`. But result is same.